# Eliminating dot separators in list of equations

Tags: equations, tocloft

In the document I'm working on I have a list of figures, list of tables, and I just added a list of equations. For the figures and tables, I'm using the tocloft package. Here's a snippet of the code that I have:

```
    \usepackage{tocloft}

    \renewcommand{\cftfigleader}{}
    \renewcommand{\cftfigafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
    \renewcommand{\cfttableader}{}
    \renewcommand{\cfttabafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
    \renewcommand{\cftequleader}{}
    \renewcommand{\cftequafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}

    % ============== TOC AND LISTS ===========
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill\bfseries\large Table of Contents\hfill}   
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@dotsep}{10000}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}%
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\newpage


\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=none}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hspace*{\fill}\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hspace*{\fill}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{List of Tables}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}.} 
{\renewcommand{\addvspace}[1]{} \listoftables}
\newpage

\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hspace*{\fill}\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hspace*{\fill}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{List of Figures}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}.}
{\renewcommand{\addvspace}[1]{} \listoffigures}
\newpage

\newcommand{\listofequationsname}{List of Equations}
\newlistof[section]{myequations}{equ}{\listofequationsname}

\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
   \addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}}
   
   \setlength{\cftmyequationsindent}{1.5em}
   \setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{2.3em}
   \renewcommand{\cftequtitlefont}{\hspace*{\fill}\large\bfseries}
   \renewcommand{\cftafterequtitle}{\hspace*{\fill}}
   
   \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{List of Equations}}
  
\listofmyequations
\newpage
```

I'm able to get the correct format that I need for the List of Figures and List of Tables using this code.

[image]

However, since the tocloft package doesn't handle equations, I haven't figured out how to do the same thing for my list of equations. I need to eliminate the dot separators and have the page number immediately after the listing just as the List of Figures.

[image]

I'm still a LaTeX newbie so thanks in advance for your help.

Here is a working example that shows a couple of tables with the format that I need in the List of Tables. It has two equations in the List of Equations with the format I am trying to change.

```
\documentclass[12pt, floatsintext]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{trace}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{none}{ }
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tocloft}%

% set page numbers just after chapter titles
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}

% set page numbers just after section titles
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}

\renewcommand{\cftsubsecleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}

\renewcommand{\cftfigleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftfigafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\renewcommand{\cfttableader}{}
\renewcommand{\cfttabafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\renewcommand{\cftequleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftequafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}


\newcommand{\atoc}[1]{\addtocontents{toc}{\bigskip #1\par}}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}  

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries\filcenter}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\large}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{30pt}{20pt}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}\counterwithout{table}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{left=4.0cm, right=2.54cm, top=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{plain}


%=======================================================
% ============== TOC AND LISTS ===========
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill\bfseries\large Table of Contents\hfill}   
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@dotsep}{10000}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}%
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\newpage


\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=none}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hspace*{\fill}\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hspace*{\fill}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{List of Tables}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}.} 
{\renewcommand{\addvspace}[1]{} \listoftables}
\newpage

\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hspace*{\fill}\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hspace*{\fill}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{List of Figures}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}.}
{\renewcommand{\addvspace}[1]{} \listoffigures}
\newpage

\newcommand{\listofequationsname}{List of Equations}
\newlistof[section]{myequations}{equ}{\listofequationsname}

\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
   \addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}}
   
   \setlength{\cftmyequationsindent}{1.5em}
   \setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{2.3em}
   \renewcommand{\cftequtitlefont}{\hspace*{\fill}\large\bfseries}
   \renewcommand{\cftafterequtitle}{\hspace*{\fill}}
   
   \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{List of Equations}}
  
\listofmyequations
\newpage

%=======================================================
% ============== CHAPTERS ===========
\newgeometry{left=4.0cm, right=2.54cm, top=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{36pt}
\doublespacing
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyheadoffset{0cm}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}%
}

\atoc{\textbf{Chapters}}
\chapter{Introduction}

\begin{table}[H]
    \begin{tabular}{l l}
        \textbf{1}  &  First Item \\
        \textbf{2}  &  Second Item \\
        \textbf{3}  &  Third Item 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Simple Table 1}
    \label{tab:simple_list1}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[H]
    \begin{tabular}{l l}
        \textbf{1}  &  First Item \\
        \textbf{2}  &  Second Item \\
        \textbf{3}  &  Third Item 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Simple Table 2}
    \label{tab:simple_list2}
\end{table}


\begin{equation} \label{eq:bellman_eq}
    \scalebox{1.5}{%
    $Q(s_{t'}, a_{t}) = E[r_{t+1} + \gamma r_{t+2} +\gamma^2 r_{t+3} + ...| s_{t'}, a_{t}] $}
\end{equation}
\myequations{Bellman Equation}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:bayestheorem_eq}
    \scalebox{1.2}{%
    $P(M|E) = \frac{P(E|M)P(M)}{P(E)} $}
\end{equation}
\myequations{Bayes' Theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete MWE (from `documentclass` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem. What class are you using (presumably not `letter`)? Where does `\captionsetup` come from? You have provided no equations.

Comment: I will create a better example. The document class is report.

Comment: Updated the question with a MWE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `eqn` with `myequations` in two lines

```tex
\renewcommand{\cfteqnleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cfteqnafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
```

(currently I get errors complaining `\cfteqnleader` and `\cfteqnafterpnum` are undefined), then move them under

```tex
\newlistof[section]{myequations}{equ}{\listofequationsname}
```

Full example (it's a bit messy)

```tex
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt, floatsintext]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{trace}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{none}{ }
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tocloft}%

% set page numbers just after chapter titles
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}

% set page numbers just after section titles
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}

\renewcommand{\cftsubsecleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}

\renewcommand{\cftfigleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftfigafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\renewcommand{\cfttableader}{}
\renewcommand{\cfttabafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}

\newcommand{\atoc}[1]{\addtocontents{toc}{\bigskip #1\par}}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}  

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries\filcenter}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\large}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{30pt}{20pt}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}\counterwithout{table}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{left=4.0cm, right=2.54cm, top=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{plain}


%=======================================================
% ============== TOC AND LISTS ===========
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill\bfseries\large Table of Contents\hfill}   
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@dotsep}{10000}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}%
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\newpage


\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=none}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hspace*{\fill}\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hspace*{\fill}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{List of Tables}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}.} 
{\renewcommand{\addvspace}[1]{} \listoftables}
\newpage

\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hspace*{\fill}\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hspace*{\fill}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{List of Figures}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}.}
{\renewcommand{\addvspace}[1]{} \listoffigures}
\newpage

\newcommand{\listofequationsname}{List of Equations}
\newlistof[section]{myequations}{equ}{\listofequationsname}

\renewcommand{\cftmyequationsleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftmyequationsafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}

\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
   \addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}}
   
   \setlength{\cftmyequationsindent}{1.5em}
   \setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{2.3em}
   \renewcommand{\cftequtitlefont}{\hspace*{\fill}\large\bfseries}
   \renewcommand{\cftafterequtitle}{\hspace*{\fill}}
   
   \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{List of Equations}}
  
\listofmyequations
\newpage

%=======================================================
% ============== CHAPTERS ===========
\newgeometry{left=4.0cm, right=2.54cm, top=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{36pt}
\doublespacing
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyheadoffset{0cm}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}%
}

\atoc{\textbf{Chapters}}
\chapter{Introduction}

\begin{table}[H]
    \begin{tabular}{l l}
        \textbf{1}  &  First Item \\
        \textbf{2}  &  Second Item \\
        \textbf{3}  &  Third Item 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Simple Table 1}
    \label{tab:simple_list1}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[H]
    \begin{tabular}{l l}
        \textbf{1}  &  First Item \\
        \textbf{2}  &  Second Item \\
        \textbf{3}  &  Third Item 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Simple Table 2}
    \label{tab:simple_list2}
\end{table}


\begin{equation} \label{eq:bellman_eq}
    \scalebox{1.5}{%
    $Q(s_{t'}, a_{t}) = E[r_{t+1} + \gamma r_{t+2} +\gamma^2 r_{t+3} + ...| s_{t'}, a_{t}] $}
\end{equation}
\myequations{Bellman Equation}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:bayestheorem_eq}
    \scalebox{1.2}{%
    $P(M|E) = \frac{P(E|M)P(M)}{P(E)} $}
\end{equation}
\myequations{Bayes' Theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This fixed it!